# Event Tracking con Google Analytics Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, google-analytics

estaba probando realizar los seguimiento de los click en mi pagina web con google analytics el caso es que tengo este tipo de div

```
<div class="container">

<a class="link" href="http://www.tree-solutions.it/it/" target="_blank">
  <img alt="st" src="https://www.socialthingum.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/tree-solution.png" width="210" height="166" class="ga">
</a>

</div>
```

e probado a incorporar el codigo para realizar los seguimiento y cada que le doy click a la imagen con el link me da en console: undefined quisiera que me dea la url del link que en este caso seria https://www.socialthingum.it/wp-content...

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$('a.link img').click(function(event){
ga('create', 'x-xxxx-x', 'auto') ; 
ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'CLICK CLIENTI', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: event.target.href });
   console.log(event.target.href);
});

});
```

Si alguien me pudiese decir en que me estoy equivocando se los agradeceria mucho ya que soy algo nuevo en esto.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `$('a.link img')` (la imagen), no tiene un atributo `href`, tiene un atributo `src`, es decir que o bien puedes cambiar el selector a `$('a.link')` y buscar el `href` con `event.currentTarget.href` o usar `event.target.src`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio mucho.